# How to address (suspected) outdated external package dependencies?

Tags: asp.net-core, nuget, asp.net-core-6.0

We have a .Net Core 6.0 solution and two of the projects have NuGet package references set to `Azure.Storage.Blobs 12.14.1` (the latest version at the time of writing):

```
<ItemGroup>
   <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Blobs" Version="12.14.1" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Today a new security scanning tool that IT are testing flagged up a "critical" issue:

> ### System.Text.Encodings.Web Remote Code Execution (RCE) CVE-2021-26701
> CVSS 9.8 Critical
>
> ```
> Introduced through: project   
> › Azure.Storage.Blobs 12.14.1 
> › System.Text.Json 4.7.2 
> › System.Text.Encodings.Web 4.7.1
> ```

I looked at the [nuget.org page for `Azure.Storage.Blobs`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Storage.Blobs#dependencies-body-tab) and it shows `System.Text.Json (>= 4.7.2)` which implied to me (perhaps wrongly) that Blobs should work just fine with later versions of Encodings.Web:

[image]

I'm only referencing `Azure.Storage.Blobs`, so does this mean that `Azure.Storage.Blobs` itself is referencing an out-of-date package?

I'm keen to avoid creating my own dependency on the nested packages when they're not directly used.  My research showed that NPM has a way around these issues, but I've been unable to find a NuGet-based solution.

Can anyone please explain what the solution is to ensure that my dependencies are kept secure here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Central package management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/central-package-management) offers a feature called [transitive pinning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/central-package-management#transitive-pinning) to manage (the versions of) transitive/indirect dependencies, without making them direct dependencies.

From the documentation

> Starting with NuGet 6.2, you can centrally manage your dependencies in your projects with the addition of a `Directory.Packages.props` file and an MSBuild property.

> You can automatically override a transitive package version even without an explicit top-level  by opting into a feature known as transitive pinning. This promotes a transitive dependency to a top-level dependency implicitly on your behalf when necessary.

---

First **enable central package management**.

Add a `Directory.Packages.props` file to e.g. the root of your repository (near your `.sln` file).

Set `ManagePackageVersionsCentrally` to `true`.

```
<ManagePackageVersionsCentrally>true</ManagePackageVersionsCentrally>
```

Include any direct NuGet packages using `PackageVersion` tags; notice the difference with `PackageReference` tags.

---

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ManagePackageVersionsCentrally>true</ManagePackageVersionsCentrally>    
  </PropertyGroup>  
  <ItemGroup>        
    <PackageVersion Include="Azure.Storage.Blobs" Version="12.14.1" />    
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Adjust your `.csproj` file(s) by removing the `version` indication from any `PackageReference` tags since this will now be managed centrally, although you can still [override](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/central-package-management#overriding-package-versions) if needed.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <ItemGroup>        
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Blobs" />
  </ItemGroup>  
</Project>
```

---

Next **enable transitive pinning** by setting `ManagePackageVersionsCentrally` to `true`.

Add below tag in a `PropertyGroup`.

```
<ManagePackageVersionsCentrally>true</ManagePackageVersionsCentrally>
```

Then include the concerning packages.
In your case you can e.g. upgrade and pin `System.Text.Json` or `System.Text.Encodings.Web` to a higher version, e.g.:

```
<PackageVersion Include="System.Text.Json" Version="6.0.7" />
```

*You need to figure out which version applies for your concrete case.*

---

Full `Directory.Package.props` example.
The transitive dependencies don't need to be in a separate `ItemGroup`, but it might be more insightful.

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ManagePackageVersionsCentrally>true</ManagePackageVersionsCentrally> 
    <CentralPackageTransitivePinningEnabled>true</CentralPackageTransitivePinningEnabled>    
  </PropertyGroup>  
  <ItemGroup>        
    <PackageVersion Include="Azure.Storage.Blobs" Version="12.14.1" />    
  </ItemGroup>
  <!-- Transitive packages -->
  <ItemGroup> 
    <PackageVersion Include="System.Text.Json" Version="6.0.7" />  
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Thank you.  That looks like a solution, although it appears that it might be something else that needs proactively managing.  Just to roll back a step first to the first part of my question - what exactly is out of date here (e.g. specifically what causes the flag to be raised)?  Is is that Microsoft have an outdated dependency somewhere in the chain?

Comment: You can see it that way. It's using the `System.Text.Json` being used and referenced by your project **or** in case you don't have this - which is your scenario -, the one mentiond `4.7.2` which has that issue.
To resolve, you'll always need some manual management until `Azure.Storage.Blob` requires higher versions. Often lower versions are being used for backwards compatibility, which works fine ... until these CVE's popup.